# Write out a dataset by inserting space after id column

Tags: r, export

I would like to write out a dataset. Here is an example of a dataset.

```
id <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
gender <- c("m","m","f","f","m","m")
score <- c(10,5,10,5,10,5)
data <- data.frame("id"=id,"gender"=gender, "score"=score)

> data
  id gender score
1  1      m    10
2  1      m     5
3  2      f    10
4  2      f     5
5  3      m    10
6  3      m     5
```

I would like to separate the id column and other variables when I export the dataset as a .dat file.

Here what I used:

```
write.table(data, file="C:/User/Desktop/data.dat", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep="", quote=FALSE)
```

The output file looks like this:

```
1m10
1m5
2f10
2f5
3m10
3m5
```

However, I want to have a .dat file looks like this:

```
1   m10
1   m5
2   f10
2   f5
3   m10
3   m5
```

In this case, the variables should start in the 5th column.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could this be usefull: `data$id <- paste0(data$id, "\t")` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `sep = ""`, there will be no space between your variables. You could use `sep = " "` to add a whitespace. If you want whitespace and no whitespace in one file, you have to manipulate your data like this:

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(genderscore = paste0(gender, score)) %>%
  select(id, genderscore)

write.table(data, file="C:/User/Desktop/data.dat", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep=" ", quote=FALSE)
```

Output:

```
1   m10
1   m5
2   f10
2   f5
3   m10
3   m5
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. After some search, I also found this useful actually. 'write.fwf(data, file = "C:/User/Desktop/data.dat", width = c(5, 1, 1), 
          colnames = FALSE, sep = "")'